# How to change direction but continue to move in Snake game using Python

Tags: python

Good Afternoon. I'm a serious beginner at coding and using Python with my first question since I can't find a solution or don't understand one.

I'm trying to build the game of snake and although I can make a rectangle move in any direction I can't keep it moving forward without a key input.

```
while True:
        keyString = win.checkKey()
        if keyString == "Left":
            snake.move(-1,0)
        elif keyString == "Right":
            snake.move(1,0)
        elif keyString == "Up":
            snake.move(0,-1)
        elif keyString == "Down":
            snake.move(0,1)
        elif keyString == "Escape":
            win.close()
```

If I write `snake.move(x,y)` below the `while True:`, it will continue to move forward but not change direction.

Any help and any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: what did you mean by it cannot change direction? you can move to left or right, isn't it correct?

Comment: Listen for user input. If you don't get any user input, let the snake move in the same direction as last move.

Comment: I just meant i could only move it a little in any direction and not have it move on its own until user input. Sorry that wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change directions upon pressing a key, and use direction to keep moving in the while loop:

```
directions = {'up': (0, -1), 'down': (0, 1), 'left': (-1, 0), 'right': (1, 0)}
direction = direction['up']                   # set a direction


while True:

    snake.move(*direction)           # move the snake at each loop, so it keeps moving
    keyString = win.checkKey()

    if keyString == "Left":          # change direction upon a key pressed
        direction = directions['left']
    elif keyString == "Right":
        direction = directions['right']
    elif keyString == "Up":
        direction = directions['up']
    elif keyString == "Down":
        direction = directions['down']

    elif keyString == "Escape":
        win.close()
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much. I got quite close to that but when i was doing it i simply used "snake.move(direction)", in which i just got back an error saying i was an argument short for .move

Comment: I wouldn't have thought about using *

Comment: In this instance, `*direction` is equivalent to `direction[0], direction[1]`